# Integration Doc / Tutorials : Microsoft Dynamics CRM with Five 9 / Etrigue

Tags: cloud-service, crm, saas

I am planning to suggest one of my clients in the US to use [Microsoft dynamics](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-login.aspx) along with [Five9](http://www.five9.com/) and [Etrigue](http://www.etrigue.com/).

These three stuffs need to be integrated to each other.

But could not find any `API` docs or tutorials for `integration` so that I could confidently suggest him and say that its possible and easy to integrate them.

please help me with helpful links
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've used CRM, never used the other two.

Five9 appears to have an native integration with CRM so you should be good there.

[Five9 Application Integration](http://www.five9.com/media_library/variation/17/Datasheet_app_integration_fnl_5_13.pdf)

And, Etriuge also appears to have a native integration with CRM.

[Stand Alone or Integrated with CRM](http://www.etrigue.com/features/demandcenter-marketing-automation/crm-integration/)

CRM doesnt have native integrations to either of those. But CRM as a product has a huge number of extensibility points and can pretty much be integrated to anything with another effort.

No idea if Five9 and Etriuge could speak to each other, though looks like you might be able to achieve communication through CRM.

So probably achievable, but worth investigating further to see how 'easy' it actually is, and what the native integrations actually provide.